# Firebase cloud messaging sonido al recibir notificacion con app cerrada

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas, estoy teniendo este problemita que no le encuentro solución. Configuré mi app para recibir notificaciones push con FCM, el tema es que cuando tengo la app cerrada entra la notificación pero no reproduce sonido y eso es lo que quisiera lograr. Alguna mano con esto?

Con esto, cuando la app esta abierta, funciona correctamente.

```
public class BarilochePcMessaginService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String LOGTAG = "android-fcm";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        String titulo = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String texto = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Log.d(LOGTAG, "NOTIFICACION RECIBIDA");
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Título: " + titulo);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Texto: " + texto);

        //Opcional: mostramos la notificación en la barra de estado
        showNotification(titulo, texto);
    }
}

private void showNotification(String title, String text) {

    String titulo = (title == null || title.isEmpty()) ? "Notificación importante" : title;

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icono)
            .setContentTitle(titulo)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, 0);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contIntent);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}}
```

Comment: Tienes algo de código de lo que haces? Como tratas de producir el sonido cuando registras el mensaje?

Comment: Ahi edité la pregunta para poner el código. Con eso reproduce sonido pero solo cuando la app esta abierta, si está cerrada solo me llega la notificacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta por mi propio medio.
Cuando envías un mensaje desde la consola de firebase hay que abrir las opciones avanzadas y seleccionar sonido habilitado, lo que por defecto sale inhabilitado y no se ve. Dejo las imágenes de ayuda.
[image: Consola de notificaciones de firebase]

[image: Opción a cambiar si queremos que la app nos avise con sonido]

Answer (score 0):

Con esto debería funcionar..

```
notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

[Documentación info.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#FLAG_HIGH_PRIORITY)

Comment: Pero esto es para cuando la app esta abierta, yo me refiero a cuando la app esta cerrada.

Comment: A mí me funciona cuando la app está cerrada, recuerda que algunas veces el SO Android destruye algunos servicios sea por baja batería o temas desconocidos.

Comment: Ok, lo voy a probar y te comento, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo controlo con estos 2 campos, el primero defino el sonido, y el segundo los zumbidos

```
 .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
 .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 300, 200, 300})
```

Pero el de vibrar necesita un permiso adicional:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

El tema de la prioridad la controlo así:

```
import android.app.Notification;
...
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar.

Answer (score 0):

> Firebase cloud messaging sonido al recibir notificacion con app
>   cerrada.

Al recibir una notificación (Push notification) es independiente si tienes abierta o cerrada la aplicación ya que al instalar la aplicación y registrar el dispositivo, se dan permisos para que el dispositivo reciba las notificaciones.

Lo que puede determinar que no se escuche es que no definas un sonido mediante el método `setSound()` o que tu deshabilites el sonido de las notificaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En lugar de definir una Uri para el sonido define el sonido default:

```
//Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
//notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
notificationBuilder.setSound(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices pero no es eso, de todos muchas gracias por la idea.

Comment: el tema del sonido que yo comente *no es el que viene por defecto*, pero es el más popular por aplicaciones como whatsapp o facebook

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que estás usando en el JSON que envías a Firebase la parte de Notification. Esto hacer que gestione Android la notificación. Te recomiendo que uses Body en lugar de Notification al enviar el JSON y en tu parte del móvil

```
remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
```

Me pasó exactamente lo mismo. Te recomiendo la respuesta de Zohab Ali de [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)

Comment: Lo voy a probar, muchas gracias.